# EXCEPTION JOIN in Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

In my ongoing transition from decades as a DB2 developer to now being an Oracle developer, I'm having a bit of a problem with some Oracle syntax.

The Oracle documentation I see on-line seems to say that EXCEPTION JOIN is supported in Oracle, but when I try to use that in Oracle 11g, it fails. What am I missing?

```
select t1.*
  from MySchema.TestingStuff_Table1 t1
;

     THEPK FIRSTNAME          
---------- --------------------
         1 Fred                 
         2 Wilma                
         3 Barney               
         4 Betty                

select t2.*
  from MySchema.TestingStuff_ExcludeThese t2
;

     THEPK
----------
         1 

select t1.*
  from MySchema.TestingStuff_Table1 t1
 where not exists (
   select *
     from MySchema.testingstuff_ExcludeThese t2
    where t2.thepk = t1.thepk
)
;

     THEPK FIRSTNAME          
---------- --------------------
         2 Wilma                
         3 Barney               
         4 Betty                

select t1.* 
  from MySchema.TestingStuff_Table1 t1
  exception join MySchema.TestingStuff_ExcludeThese t2
    on t2.thePK = t1.thePK
;

Error at Command Line:3 Column:3
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
```

Thanks for your help!
DaveSlash

Comment: "*The Oracle documentation I see on-line*" - which documentation is that? Can you add the link?

Comment: I had never heard of an EXCEPTION JOIN before. After checking the DB2 documentation it appears that Oracle refers to this as an "anti-join". I've looked through the 11.1, 11.2, and 12.1 Oracle SQL Reference manuals and can't find documentation on the EXCEPTION JOIN syntax - Oracle says that to do this the NOT EXISTS or NOT IN constructs should be used. Please update the question with a doc ref. Many thanks (and +1).

Comment: Apparently, I was mistaken. Upon further research, it appears that EXCEPTION JOIN is not supported in Oracle. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

It seems to have problem with alias. This will work:

```
select MySchema.TestingStuff_Table1.*
from MySchema.TestingStuff_Table1 
exception join MySchema.TestingStuff_ExcludeThese 
on TestingStuff_ExcludeThese.thePK = TestingStuff_Table1.thePK
;
```

Comment: This is not valid Oracle syntax.